num_format not applying to Excel Column
Hope someone can shed some light on this as this has beaten me so far today.
Context:
I have a pandas dataframe styled via the pandas styler which I am exporting via a file dialgue so a file name can be entered with the correct extension via the windows file dialogue GUI using tkinter.
During the export process I am using xlsxwriter to format the column width and to format the column with the correct data type which is a GBP currency field £1,234.00
The column width and worksheet zoom setting applies perfectly fine. However the data type is not applying.
Expected Result:
£1,234.00
Actual Result
1234.00
Code below.
        with filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".xlsx", filetypes=[("Excel files", ".xlsx .xls")]) as file:
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file.name, engine="xlsxwriter")
            styler.to_excel(writer, columns=['Consultant','Dept','T/S ID','Client','Candidate','P/E Date','Charge','Pay','Split GP','Split %','Margin%','Comm %','Comm Value','Perm Salary','Placement'], index=False, sheet_name= "561 Comms")
            workbook = writer.book
            worksheet = writer.sheets['561 Comms']

            number_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format' : '0'})
            money_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format' : '£#,##0.00'})
            rate_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format' : '#0.00%'})

            worksheet.set_zoom(80)
            worksheet.set_column('G:I', 20, money_fmt)
            worksheet.set_column('J:L', 12, rate_fmt)
            writer.close()
        except AttributeError as ae:
            print(ae)

The excel file exports and saves perfectly fine - it is just the number_fmt, money_fmt and rate_fmt lines which do not seem to be working properly.
Any information or advice would be massively appreciated!
Thanks
Formatting an Excel Column using Python xlsxwriter
Expected Result:
£1,234.00
Actual Result
1234.00

Most probably the type of the data for those columns are strings, not numbers, so the format does not apply on them.

The format for using set_column is fine. What does the Pandas Styler do? This does not work as a synchronous set of events, Pandas Styler does something then the Xlsxwriter does something. Get rid of the styler and use df.to_excel, otherwise the number formatting from Xlsxwriter wont work. Use Xlsxwriter for the styling.

@moken that done it! Didn't realise the two conflicted with each other. I just re-did the row formatting in the xlsxwriter instead. Thanks a million!

For the set_column look at the documents this is what I notice

worksheet.set_column(first_col, last_col, width, cell_format, options)
Parameters:

first_col (int) – First column (zero-indexed).
last_col (int) – Last column (zero-indexed). Can be same as first_col.
width (float) The width of the column(s), in character units.
cell_format (Format) Optional Format object.
options (dict) – Optional parameters: hidden, level, collapsed.


for an example if you wanted to have the column G to have a money format money_fmt you would do it like this.
worksheet.set_column(6, 6, 20, money_fmt)

it is probably better to be explicit like this
worksheet.set_column(first_col=6, last_col=6, width=20, cell_format=money_fmt)


Also you did not save the work.
writer._save()



let me know if this worked or not. The only other thing I can think of is a number format like "£#,##0.00_);[Red]-£#,##0.00_);0_);_(@_)"

writer save is not necessary. The writer.close() will save and close file handles.

@ShaneS - Moken's fixed this for me. I was using both pandas styler code and xlsxwriter formatting. Thanks anyway!

@moken comment was correct. I was using styler commands before the dataframe was passed to the xlsxwriter. Removing the styler code and changing styler.to_excel to df.to_excel fixed this for me.
